# LINQ Select - CS0411 The type arguments cannot be inferred from the usage error

Tags: c#, linq, async-await

I'm trying to convert a `foreach` loop into a `Select` statement as follows:

ForEach loop

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
foreach (var proxyRequest in proxyRequests)
{
    tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        try
        {
            Logger.LogInformation($"Request for the enrichment Giact [{message.SalesforceId}] \n {JsonSerializer.Serialize(proxyRequest)}");
            var result = await InquiryClient.CreateInquiry(proxyRequest, cancellationToken);

            Logger.LogInformation($"Response for the enrichment Giact [{message.SalesforceId}] \n {JsonSerializer.Serialize(result.Result)}");
            Response.GiactInquiryResponses.Add(result.Result);
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             Logger.LogError($"Error on requesting the enrichment Giact [{message.SalesforceId}] \n {ex}");
         }
     }));
}
```

Select Statement:

```
proxyRequests.Select(x => tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () =>
{
    try
    {
        Logger.LogInformation($"Request for the enrichment Giact [{message.SalesforceId}] \n {JsonSerializer.Serialize(x)}");
        var result = await InquiryClient.CreateInquiry(x, cancellationToken);

        Logger.LogInformation($"Response for the enrichment Giact [{message.SalesforceId}] \n {JsonSerializer.Serialize(result.Result)}");
        Response.GiactInquiryResponses.Add(result.Result);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.LogError($"Error on requesting the enrichment Giact [{message.SalesforceId}]\n {ex}");
    }
})));
```

But it gives me the CS0411 error. I've searched a bit and i found that the `Select` statement expects a return value and that a `foreach` loop is more suited to do this job.

Is that so? Can the same result be achieved with a `Select` statement?

Comment: `Select` is not a replacement for `foreach` and should not be used as one. As just one example, your `Select` statement code will not run any `Add` methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Select` is a projection method, so your action inside select should return something. But your `List.Add` is `void`.

Try the following

```
var tasks = proxyRequests.Select(x => Task.Run(()=>{/* your task code here */})).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to project each `proxyRequest` to a `Task`, and then materialize the deferred `IEnumerable<Task>` to a list of tasks by using the [`ToList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolist) operator:

```
List<Task> tasks = proxyRequests.Select(x => Task.Run(async () =>
{
    try
    {
        Logger.LogInformation($"Request for the enrichment Giact " 
            + $"[{message.SalesforceId}] \n {JsonSerializer.Serialize(x)}");
        var result = await InquiryClient.CreateInquiry(x, cancellationToken);

        Logger.LogInformation($"Response for the enrichment Giact "
            + $"[{message.SalesforceId}] \n {JsonSerializer.Serialize(result.Result)}");
        Response.GiactInquiryResponses.Add(result.Result);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.LogError($"Error on requesting the enrichment Giact"
            + $" [{message.SalesforceId}]\n {ex}");
    }
})).ToList();
```

Beware that the `Response.GiactInquiryResponses.Add` method may be invoked by multiple threads concurrently, so, unless it is thread-safe, it may result to undefined behavior (corrupted internal state, random exceptions etc). In general it is preferable to avoid side-effects inside the body of each task, and instead propagate naturally its result:

```
List<Task<SomeType>> tasks = proxyRequests.Select(x => Task.Run(async () =>
{
    var result = await InquiryClient.CreateInquiry(x, cancellationToken);
    return result.Result;
})).ToList();

SomeType[] results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```